# Bootstrap form JS validation in loop

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

What is the correct way to get an form validation when there is an in a loop?
($i set somewhere else)

```
  <form class="form-calculator" id="edit'.$i.'" action="includes/processing/manual_edit_processing.php" method="post">
  <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="div_edit_naam['.$i.']">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_naam['.$i.']" name="edit_naam['.$i.']" placeholder="Naam" value="'.$row_list['naam'].'" onkeyup="validate_edit(this, '.$i.'))" onmousemove="validate_edit(this, '.$i.')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="edit_naam_status['.$i.']">
            </div>
        </div>

     </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </form>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.reload()">Sluiten</button>
    <button type="button" id="submit_edit'.$i.'" alt="'.$i.'" class="btn btn-primary edit">Bewerk</button>
  </div>
```

Above is my HTML part, below my JS part, I think I have messed up with the ID's unique?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() { document.getElementById('submit_edit[]')[nr].disabled = true; }

function validate_edit(selectVeld, nr)
{
    // edit_naam
    if(document.getElementById('edit_naam[]')[nr].value.length < 5) { document.getElementById('div_edit_naam[]')[nr].className = "form-group has-warning has-feedback"; document.getElementById('edit_naam_status[]')[nr].className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else
    { document.getElementById('div_edit_naam[]')[nr].className = "form-group has-success has-feedback"; document.getElementById('edit_naam_status[]')[nr].className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }

    // Submit form
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('has-error').length > 0 || document.getElementsByClassName('has-warning').length > 0) { document.getElementById('submit_edit').disabled = true; }
    else { document.getElementById('submit_edit').disabled = false; }
}
</script>
```

Comment: OK, thhx trincot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("edit_naam["+nr+"]")
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('edit_naam[]')[nr]
```

Most of the ID you set to the HTML elements have this format `something[index]` so that is the construct you should pass as a parameter to the `document.getElementById` function. `document.getElementById('edit_naam[]')[nr]` doesn't make any sense since this function returns only one HTML element.

Also, `[` and `]` are not accepted characters for IDs in HTML 4.

Comment: These changes are not giving another result.

Comment: @Muiter you'll have to edit all the `document.getElementById` calls to be like that. You should also take a look at the generated HTML to see what the actual IDs of the elements are.

Comment: Yes I know I am bit of a newby to JS, but I did understand that I needed to change alles ID's.

Comment: @Muiter Just open the page in a browser, *right click* it and select **View Page Source** to get a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: OK, Got that part working now. THX. But how to use <button type="button" id="submit_edit'.$i.'" alt="'.$i.'" class="btn btn-primary edit">Bewerk</button> so it will be disabled at start en enabled when all classes are set OK ?